# Bundles, Workflow and Blueprinting

Tags: 2013-sp1, workflow, bundles

Right what I want to do is simple.. but think it might not be allowed.
I have 3 publications (Master, Site1 (Child of Master), Site2 (Child of Master)).

I make a change in master (a new site section, so some templates components and pages, new and changes). I place the whole lot into a bundle.

Site1 wants it to go live so using my simple workflow checks it on staging and approves it to live.

Site2 want to wait to go live for a week.

Will this work using Bundles? If so how as when I tried it appeared that when I put the bundle into workflow on Site1 it then approved it to all sites....

Any ideas?

Thanks

Graeme

Answer (score 1):

You can do this.  To get perspective on the functionality if this was done manually, you'd create the bundle in the master (as you've described), then you would publish it separately within the respective publication contexts (site 1 and site 2).

So, now you want to add some automation to this, i.e. workflow. Simply code your workflow logic to have a Decision step that will branch out into two Automated Activities like "Publish to Site 1" and "Publish to Site 2". The logic of the Automated Activities will be using the Core Service or TOM.NET API to publish the bundle within the respective context.

Comment: Nickoli, yes that would work apart from on old content that might need to be re-published with the old version whilst still waiting on the current one to be approved.
But thinking about it if I split then regroup I could maybe be able to do something like it. Although that is probably going Parallel to make it...

Comment: In terms of timing, you could schedule publishing for later (choosing to render now or later) or even suspend workflow to start again later.

Comment: Debating localizing the items, localized work flow then tidying it all up at the end of the process....... messy but would do the job